# Trying to make a sorted dynamic list ( data structure)

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Good evening everyone. The program which I am making right now is related to sorting and data structure. I have already inputted some values in my list. I want to sort them, in order to do so I extract the values present at each individual node into an array and then sort the array. I am having a confusion regarding putting the sorted values into the list.

This is the code which contains the structure, class and function definition ( the full definition of class is not mentioned)

```cpp
#define max 30

struct data
{
 int val,index;
 data* next;
};

class exp
{
 data* beg;int count;
 int arr[max];
 public:
 exp()
 {beg = NULL;
  count = 0;}
};
```

The confusion I am having is because of this:

```cpp
void exp :: sort_ins()
{
 sort();
 data* temp = beg;
 int i = 0;
 do
 {
   temp -> val = arr[i];
   temp = temp -> next;
   i++;
 }while(i < count && temp != NULL);

}
```

My question is that after changing the values associated with temp ( which is basically going from beginning to end) will actually change the value of nodes associated with "beg"? I mean to say that after executing this code, if I try to obtain value of nodes attached to "beg", would the values have been updated? Or do I need to add something else? If possible, I would like a link to relevant theory for learning purposes( purely optional).

Thank you for your time..

(I haven't given the full code, I can share if required.)

Comment: Use a `std::vector` and `std::sort` and be done already.

Comment: If the items are already sorted in the array, just rebuild a new list from scratch with the sorted items.

Comment: As a general rule, asking for off site resources is off topic for SO. That said, you can try [this](https://gist.github.com/ericandrewlewis/720c374c29bbafadedc9). And, you can always google *C++ Pointers* too. That should give you some nice links too.

Comment: Thank you everyone. Your insights have been very useful. Honestly @PaulMcKenzie I never thought of that, its extremely simple....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, changing what `temp` is pointing at also changes was `beg` is pointing at because they're both pointing at the same data.

If you copy a pointer, you end up with two pointers pointing at the same thing. And either pointer could be used to change that thing. That's how pointers work.